# Check/Uncheck image's checkbox if not dropped/dragged

Tags: jquery

I have a grid with images and every image has an checkbox to select it (for delete). The grid is sortable.

I want to check/uncheck the checkbox only if the image is not drapped/dropped (by simple click only).

I have done the following lines

```
$('#images li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).children('input').is(':checked'))
    {
         $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).children('input').attr('checked', true);
    }
});

$('#image li').bind('drag',function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
});

$('#image li').bind('drop',function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
});
```

However the "drop" statement look doesn't work. How to do it right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution! I've changed the "click()" to "live()" as it works correctly.
The correct code:

```
$('#images li').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).children('input').is(':checked'))
    {
         $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).children('input').attr('checked', true);
    }
});

$('#image li').bind('drag',function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
});

$('#image li').bind('drop',function() {
    $(this).children('input').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `drop` event is not what you think it is in this example.  This is an event fired on the object that is *dropped on*, not the object that is *dropped*.  You're looking for the `dragend` event.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljsluknm.php